# HTML markup in XML / XSLT

Tags: xml, perl, perl-module

Part of a script that generates XML that is ingested by XSLT and spit out to an HTML web page.

```
use XML::Writer ;
$writer->emptyTag('Row' , 'text' => $text  ) ;
```

Works great, but now I want to put some HTML markup in there...  Instead of:

```
$text = "Line of text." ;
```

I need:

```
$text = qq |<span class="blah">Line of text.</span>| ;
```

Tried changing

```
<
```

to

```
&lt;
```

and

```
>
```

to

```
&gt;
```

in the string but didn't work...

(UPDATE:  Responding to a comment here...  When I said it "didn't work", specifically, the attempt to pass through HTML markup was unsuccessful, because the markup was displayed instead of being processed.  In other words, the tags weren't applied, they just showed up as part of the text.  AC)

Thanks all.  I'm learning...

Comment: "It didn't work" is a [very bad description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114574/encourage-problem-descriptions) of your problem.

Comment: I found the solution. 

I changed:

    <xsl:value-of select="@text" />

... in my XSLT file, to:

    <xsl:value-of select="@text" disable-output-escaping="yes" />

Working perfectly.

Thanks to everybody.

AC

Answer (score 3):

The `emptyTag` call is working as expected, but it looks like XML::Writer is not going to try and be smart for you and figure out if you are passing data that results in badly-formed XML.

From the docs at [https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Writer](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aWriter)

> emptyTag($name [, $aname1 => $value1, ...])
>
> ```
> Add an empty tag to an XML document. Any arguments after the element
> ```
>
> name are assumed to be name/value pairs for attributes (see startTag() for details):

So, to get the XML `<span class="blah">Line of text.</span>` as a result, you would do something like this:

```
use XML::Writer;

my $writer = new XML::Writer;

$writer->startTag('span',class=>'blah');
$writer->characters('Line of text.');
$writer->endTag();
```

Comment: Thanks mrk.  I'll try playing with it.  I was hoping to be able to pass through the single string in the XML somehow where I could put as few or as many HTML tags in there and they'd all be processed accordingly instead of just displayed...  but like you said, it seems like you're right on the money - the module isn't trying to keep the xml properly formed.